# multiplication speed for different primitive types

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-architecture

Does multiplication speed are the same for byte, short, int, and long or it grows logarithmically, linearly, exponentially?
I wrote a small program to test it. the result all returns 0;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    short a = 0xffea, b = 0xffaa;
    int result, ia = 0xffeaffae, ib = 0xeaffaeff;
    long iresult, la = 0xffeaffaeffdaffad, lb = 0xeaffaeffdaffadff;
    long long lresult;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    result = a * b;
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start);

    cout << "short multiplication : " << dur.count() << endl;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    iresult = ia * ib;
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    dur = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start);

    cout << "int multiplication : " << dur.count() << endl;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    lresult = la * lb;
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    dur = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start);

    cout << "long multiplication : " << dur.count() << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

I assume a 64bits processor can compute primitive types in same speed;

Thanks

Comment: Timing in a PC is too coarse to be able to measure one arithmetic operation. You need to run millions of them and average.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers - it prevents us from compiling it. Also, if you are not specifically asking about POSIX code, don't include headers like <unistd.h>.

Comment: All your numbers are known at compile time, your compiler might optimize out most of this code.

Comment: Yes, multiplication times differ for the different data types.  Depends on the processor.  With modern, 32-bit processors, the times should be measured in *nanoseconds*.  Small enough that unless you are performing 1E9 operations, the times are insignificant and usually a lot less than waiting for a task switch, or an I/O operation.

Comment: Numbers whose type is smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` for arithmetic operations, so, in general, there is no speed benefit from using smaller types.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's what logically happens in the C++ abstract machine.  Adding two `uint8_t` numbers and assigning the result to `uint8_t` can optimize to a single-byte `add` instruction thanks to the as-if rule, because it always gives the same result as widening, doing a wider add, and then taking only the low byte of the result.  This can be very important when the compiler auto-vectorizes your code; narrower types mean more elements per SIMD vector.  (If the compiler manages to avoid widening like the C rules say; sometimes gcc and clang do a really bad job...)

Comment: @PeterCordes — the question mentions `byte`, which is not even an arithmetic type, and `short`. I don’t think it’s about SIMD optimization’s for single-byte unsigned types. If you want to explain all those details to a beginner feel free; I stand by my comment.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I have over a dozen other half-finished answers to other questions in need of detailed answers to clear up major confusion... Questions with massive misunderstandings of performance and testing methodology come in faster than I can keep up with them with good answers, so sometimes I just comment :/  Pelipap already linked https://agner.org/optimize/, which which the OP should go read to learn more about how C++ compiles to asm for x86, and what's efficient in x86 asm.

Comment: @Pete - yours is a common misconception! The C++ promotion semantics are probably not relevant here, unless your compiler is pretty bad. Compilers easily track the true size/ranges of underlying values through casts, promotion, assignments and so on and emit larger or smaller operations at the assembly level as it suits them if the result is the same.

Comment: @Bee: your \@Pete notified me.  (And I assume not \@PeteBecker.)  Might want to repost that comment.

Comment: Yeah that was was for @peteb lol name collision (I wonder how SO chooses in that case?)

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Probably most recent match (not including your own username, so I can't check with autocomplete).

Answer (score 1):

It is machine dependent. For native datatypes, the number of cycles consumed for the multiplication instructions is relevant. To definitely tell the used instructions, use inline assembly or check the assembly output. For intel processors, [this document](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) lists cpu cycles for many instructions.

The [rtdsc instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter), amongst others like cpuid might give you a rough idea about how many cpu cycles are used by parts of your code but you're probably better of studying assembly or profiling your application.

But most of the time, none of this is relevant for practice. They take around one cycle, that is something like around 0,000000001 seconds.

In most cases, you can stick to your assumption and regard multiplication to have the same cost for all native datatypes.

Comment: More importantly, the `*` binary operator in C++ source doesn't always compile to a multiply instruction.  In this case, constant propagation means the multiply optimizes away entirely.  (Unless you compile the OP's code with optimization disabled, in which case you're benchmarking the loads/stores to the stack.  Of course there's way too much overhead to accurately measure as *single* multiply's cost; you need to do it in a loop for either throughput or latency.)  Anyway, with auto-vectorization, `short` is better than `int` (SSE4.1 `pmullo` is slow), and `int64_t` needs AVX512 for SIMD mul.